# NFS There was a problem connecting to the server

Tags: finder, nas, nfs

I have this message: There was a problem connecting to the server ... contact your System Administrator. Whenever I try Finder > Go > Connect to Server > `nfs://192.168.1.100/mnt/nfs-share`

If I type `showmount -e 192.168.1.100` then `/mnt/nfs-share 192.168.1.0/24` is listed. What is going on? Why can't Finder connect to the server? Windows connects fine. Should I try to mount the share from the command line?

Comment: `mount_nfs 192.168.1.100:/mnt/nfs-share` gives the output: `mount_nfs: can't mount with remote locks when server (192.168.1.100) is not running rpc.statd: RPC prog. not avail`

Comment: I've added `nfs.client.mount.options = resvport` to `/etc/nfs.conf` but now I get: `mount_nfs: can't mount /mnt/nfs-share from 192.168.1.100 onto /Users/josephashford/NFS: Operation not permitted` when I try to mount. I don't know what to do.